# How do I expose my incoming Ingress traffic to both IPv4 or IPv6 on AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, ipv6, azure-aks

I am working with the [kubernetes/ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) helm chart and I would like to "DualStack" both IPv4 and IPv6 on the same Ingress controller.

The helm chart [controller.service.loadBalancerIP](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/a08296256f28d534728624013e775e96b65f6e16/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L263) only accepts a string and I assume that can only be a single IP address. IPv4 or IPv6.

**How do I expose my Ingress traffic to both IPv4 or IPv6 on AKS ?**

*(I don't want to set up two ingress controllers for this)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Kubernetes v1.16 [IPv4/IPv6 dual-stack](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dual-stack/#enable-ipv4-ipv6-dual-stack) is added as *alpha* feature, which means you need to enable it via [feature gates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/).

> To enable IPv4/IPv6 dual-stack, enable the  `IPv6DualStack`  [feature gate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/)  for the relevant components of your cluster, and set dual-stack cluster network assignments:
>
> - kube-apiserver:
>   -   `--feature-gates="IPv6DualStack=true"`
> - kube-controller-manager:
>   -   `--feature-gates="IPv6DualStack=true"`
>   -   `--cluster-cidr=<IPv4 CIDR>,<IPv6 CIDR>`
>   -   `--service-cluster-ip-range=<IPv4 CIDR>,<IPv6 CIDR>`
>   -   `--node-cidr-mask-size-ipv4|--node-cidr-mask-size-ipv6`  defaults to /24 for IPv4 and /64 for IPv6
> - kubelet:
>   -   `--feature-gates="IPv6DualStack=true"`
> - kube-proxy:
>   -   `--cluster-cidr=<IPv4 CIDR>,<IPv6 CIDR>`
>   -   `--feature-gates="IPv6DualStack=true"`
>
> **Note:**  An example of an IPv4 CIDR:  `10.244.0.0/16`  (though you would supply your own address range) An example of an IPv6 CIDR:  `fdXY:IJKL:MNOP:15::/64`  (this shows the format but is not a valid address - see  [RFC 4193](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193))

You also need a CNI which will support the dual-stack for example Calico and you can check how to [Enable dual stack](https://docs.projectcalico.org/networking/dual-stack).

Unfortunately I do not know how to do that on AKS.

Comment: Dual stack is finally Stable 1.23 https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-1-23-whats-new/

Answer (score 1):

To allow both IPv4 and IPV6, the easiest would be to configure two kubernetes service for your NGINX Ingress Controller.

Deploy your Charts normally and augment it with a raw kubernetes manifest based on https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/charts/ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service.yaml

one service will default to the IPFamily IPv4 while the second service should set the ipFamily to IPv6

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dual-stack/#services

This will allow you to have to frontendIP ready to handle the IPv4 and IPv6 traffic.

You could then used the external-DNS service to have both IPs (v4/v6) with the same DNS hostname. (one A record, and one AAAA record).

Comment: Thanks, but what do you need to augment in the controller service?

Comment: you will need to set the ipFamily in the second Service-Controller file to IPV6: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dual-stack/#services